# Question about level set.

Tags: calculus, geometry

let $f(x,y,z) = \frac{x^2}{9} + \frac{y^2}{45} + \frac{-z^2}{80} $. 
and let $S$ be the level set of $f$ that goes through the point $P_0= (2,5,0)$

- What kind of level set is this?
- Show that there are two lines that go through the point $P_0=(2,5,0)$ and all of the points of the lines are on the level S. find the Canonical equation of the two lines.

to decided what kind of level is this I substituted the point $P_0$ in the equation $f(x,y,z) = \frac{x^2}{9} + \frac{y^2}{45} + \frac{-z^2}{80} $. and got that $f(x,y,z)=1$
so, in that case $\frac{x^2}{9} + \frac{y^2}{45} + \frac{-z^2}{80}=1$ represents a Hyperboloid of one sheet. and I'm not sure if this is the answer. for second part Im thinking about substituting in the equation a general formula for a line and see what result I get, But I didn't know how to do this technically. I know that in order to find a general canonical equation I need a point and a vector, here I have the point $(2,5,0)$ but how do I find a vector ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, such a line will be parametrized by $x = az + 2, y = bz + 5$ unless the line lies on the plane $z = 0$, which is easy to see not to be the case.  In a more general case, the linear equations for $x$ and $y$ would have unknown constant terms, but we can plug in $(2,5,0)$, a known point on our line.

At this point, you need to force the equation $\frac{(az+2)^2}{9} + \frac{(bz+5)^2}{45} - \frac{z^2}{80} = 1$ to be true for all $z$.  This is pure algebra, and the correct solutions should be reasonable to obtain.

Comment: can u explain more how did u get that $x=az+2$ and $y=bz+5$ ? shouldn't there be another parameter $t$ instead of $z$ ?

Comment: First, consider the projection of our line to the $xz$-plane.  This will usually be a line of the form $x = az + c$ for constants $a,c$.  The only exceptions are when the projection is a line of the form $z = c$ for $c$ constant, or when the projection is a point, meaning that $x$ and $z$ are both constants.  It's easy to rule out those degenerate cases here.  Now plug in $(x,y,z) = (2, 5, 0)$ to get $2 = a(0) + c$ to see that $c = 2$.  The other equation is similar.

Comment: Im just trying to imagine this in a 3 dimensions, its not that intuitive though.

Comment: Maybe it's easier to imagine the line parameterized over time as $(at+ 2, bt+5, ct+0)$, where $(a,b,c)$ is a vector parallel to the line, and the constant terms have been chosen such that the given point $(2,5,0)$ is at time $t=0$.  If we assume $c \ne 0$, then we can solve $t = z/c$, which lets us rewrite our line as $(a'z + 2, b'z + 5, z)$, where $a' = a/c, b' = b/c$.

Comment: Awesome! now I got it. all I need now is to do the algebra and see what I get, Thanks bro :)